# How can I simulate a touch in a UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, youtube, youtube-api

I want to automatically play a YouTube video but because of how YouTube's view counter is set up, autoplay views will not count as views.

How can I simulate a user interaction tap in a `UIWebView` so YouTube thinks that the user pressed/tapped play?

Or do you "think" that a very near version of `iOS` will support this? 
Trying to phrase that in NDA accordance. Do you think it would work if I changed the user agent of the `UIWebView` to a desktop user agent and displayed a standard YouTube page?

On the desktop YouTube videos autoplay on Youtube.com but this does not work on mobile.

I have set `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` to no.

Comment: Youtube has better anti autoclick detection than you seem to think.

Comment: Ugh, I was afraid of answers like that. I don't see how possible it is for them to protect it. With non-public APIs this is easy.

Comment: @Overcode What about my user agent idea? Would that not work?

Comment: Youtube obviously doesn't have a public API for reasons like this.
The site records some other information that you probably don't have, most notably IP, which I believe is their main method of tracking clicks.

Comment: @Overcode I was talking about an iOS API. And the IP would not matter because the request would originate from a UIWebView on the clients network without my server as an intermediary.

Comment: Youtube would probably read that as a click. But then again this isn't something you could do 100 times per second, youtube would pick that up pretty quickly.